# libpynumero_ASL is it available fror windows?

Tags: pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

Just curious if libpynumero_ASL.dll is available for windows or it is only installable through linux/ios OS using pynumero libraries in conda?

Answer (score 0):

You can now install pynumero libraries via conda in windows

conda install -c conda-forge pynumero_libraries